# Problem with setting msg.value of a transaction

Tags: solidity, transactions, ethers.js, bignumber

First, let's pay attention that this Dapp is deployed on Polygon test net, so it works with MATIC tokens, and all the calculations should comply with this fact.

Within the function below, a string should be provided as the function's parameter for witnessing proper interaction. At the same time, a specific amount of ether should be sent with the transaction to the contract as the msg.value.

[image]

On the other hand, here is the function of my JS Script ( for user interface ) in which I try to execute the payDong( ) function via the **ethers.js** library.

[image]

However, I believe I am doing something wrong because, at each execution, I am given the error below in my browser's console regarding the transaction's **msg.value**.

[image]

I know that every integer meant to get sent to the Blockchain should be converted to a big number, but as the dong value could sometimes be a fractional number, I could not to come up with an excellent solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg.value` [is defined](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) as `uint256` and is used to pass the number of **wei** sent with the message. Hence you cannot use fractional numbers with `msg.value`. The possible solution is to denominate your `dong` variable in "wei".

With ethers.js you can use the following code:

```js
const maticsInWei = ethers.utils.parseEther("1.2");
// Value of maticsInWei: BigNumber { value: "1200000000000000000" }
```

Comment: Can you give an example with a line of code?

Comment: I guess there must be a certain Ethers.js library to ensure desirable functionality

Comment: Updated my answer with example

Comment: Yes! That's correct :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, while setting **msg.value** for a transaction meant to be broadcast to a Blockchain from our JS code, the format should be a **BigNumber**. This is usually achieved by `ethers.utils.parseEther("value")`

On the other hand, while reading a value that is retrieved from Blockchain, we should convert the BigNumber into a string or number to work with, usually with `ethers.utils.formatEther("retrievedValue")`